# Unable to understand why error not throw when table name is different

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to understand what is happening why it is not throwing me error.

Currently I have 2 tables

**Table 1** `-> students`

**Table 2** `-> employees`

**Note :** Both the tables have the **same column name** and **same data**. As I created using `create table employees as select * from students;`

**This are the column names for both tables** `-> student_id  , student_name , student_marks`

**My code :**

-- My code is strongly type ref cursor

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE
     TYPE s_ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR RETURN students%rowtype;
     v_cur  s_ref_cursor;
     v_stud students%rowtype;
BEGIN
     OPEN v_cur FOR SELECT
                   *
               FROM
                   students;

     LOOP
          FETCH v_cur INTO v_stud;
          EXIT WHEN v_cur%notfound;
          dbms_output.put_line(v_stud.student_id
                         || ','
                         || v_stud.student_name
                         || ','
                         || v_stud.student_marks);  
     END LOOP;

     CLOSE v_cur;
END;
```

The above code gives me **output**  which is mention below

**Output :**

```
544,Britney,95

32,Kristeen,100

544,Dyana,95

544,Jenny,95
```

Now what I observed is 2nd table `-> employee` also hold same data and same column name as of `student` table.

I replace this below following code

**From**

```
OPEN v_cur FOR SELECT
                       *
                   FROM
                       students
```

**To**

```
OPEN v_cur FOR SELECT
                       *
                   FROM
                       employees
```

**2nd code :**

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE
     TYPE s_ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR RETURN students%rowtype;
     v_cur  s_ref_cursor;
     v_stud students%rowtype;
BEGIN
     OPEN v_cur FOR SELECT
                   *
               FROM
                   employees;

     LOOP
          FETCH v_cur INTO v_stud;
          EXIT WHEN v_cur%notfound;
          dbms_output.put_line(v_stud.student_id
                         || ','
                         || v_stud.student_name
                         || ','
                         || v_stud.student_marks);  
     END LOOP;

     CLOSE v_cur;
END;
```

When I run the 2nd code. It as given me output why so ?.

Basically it should throw me error according to strongly type ref cursor.

As I implicitly mentioned  -> `TYPE s_ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR RETURN students%rowtype;`

Answer (score 0):

> Basically it should throw me error according to strongly type ref cursor.

No, it should not.

A strongly-typed cursor is just a cursor with a data-type that is external to the query used to generate the cursor; it does not mean that it is locked to only data from that source.

For example, you can define your own strongly-typed cursors based on a `RECORD`. In which case, there would not be a table to restrict the cursor to selecting rows from:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE some_data IS RECORD(
    a NUMBER,
    b VARCHAR2(20),
    c DATE
  );
  TYPE some_data_cursor IS REF CURSOR RETURN some_data;

  v_cur  some_data_cursor;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cur FOR
    SELECT LEVEL,
           CHR(64+LEVEL),
           SYSDATE + LEVEL
    FROM   DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

  DECLARE
    TYPE other_data IS RECORD(
      a INTEGER,
      b CHAR(1),
      c DATE
    );
    v_data other_data;
  BEGIN  
    LOOP
      FETCH v_cur INTO v_data;
      EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_data.a || ', ' || v_data.b || ', ' || v_data.c);
    END LOOP;
  END;
  CLOSE v_cur;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    CLOSE v_cur;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 1, A, 2023-03-08 09:42:12
> 2, B, 2023-03-09 09:42:12
> 3, C, 2023-03-10 09:42:12
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xJTIEyjq)

You also do not need to fetch the cursor into the same type as it is strongly-typed to; just so long as the data fits into the type(s) you are using the code will compile and run.

Comment: If I am not wrong because of holding same type  so the data is printed for me.

Comment: @shayaaz It does not have to be the same type; just so long as the data can be coerced to fit the data type. For example [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tzpoC3eJ) is putting the data into a cursor with different data types and it works (there may be some truncating of data to get it to fit but, when it needs to, Oracle will perform the type coercion automatically and if it cannot coerce the data types then it will raise an exception).